# Как отобразить изображение с сокета в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pil

Всем привет! Пишу маленькое приложение на python. Есть сервер и клиент
На сервере есть База данных в ней хранятся изображение(BLOB sqlite3), клиент посылает запрос и сервер предоставляет изображение дальше клиент по данным от изображения пытается отобразить его.
Но когда я пытаюсь отобразить изображение происходит ошибка в этой строке кода:

> photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=getimg(1))

Вот ошибка:
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'

никак не могу разобраться в чём ошибка.